# What is the best way to UNION me with my friends in FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I want the equivalent of `SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me() UNION SELECT me()`. I want this so that I can plug it into other queries and get the information for all users, not just friends. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: How about a simple OR …?

Comment: I thought about that, but then I get a list of my friends with my id appearing as many times as my friends are on it, and because of the 5000 item limit, im worried that some people will get dropped off of it.

Comment: Nope, not if you put the OR in the right place: `SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me()) OR uid = me()`

Answer (score 1):

We are using next FQL query:

```
    select uid1,uid2 FROM friend where uid1=me() OR uid2=me()
```

That gives you an not normalized array of friendship, it contains duplicates entries, both your friendship rel with friend and him friendship with you

Answer (score 0):

CBroe is right `SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me()) OR uid = me()` should return

- a list of friends and
- the current user